# Textarea with Trigger - how to add trigger to tab-through

Tags: extjs

The following form is nearly completely editable without mouse:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gsi

The only thing that is not accessible is the trigger of the textareafield.

Since the textareafield is typeable, I would like to make the trigger of the textareafield tabbable. Tab is the only thing I think I can use without hindering general ability to type.

How can I do this? I have not found anything in the [trigger documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.trigger.Trigger.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite a complete answer, but too long to be a comment, and it might be helpful to you. Here is one possible solution: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gt8

I have overridden the trigger's `renderTpl` config by making the top level element a `button` (by default it is a `div`), and I've added some styling to it.

You can make the `div` tabable with [tabindex](https://allyjs.io/data-tables/focusable.html#tabindex-attribute), but the issue will be that when you press enter on the focused trigger, it will not execute the handler.

With the current approach, the single issue is that the textarea's focused styling gets messed up. When you press press tab after being focused on the trigger, the textarea will still keep the focused class.

Comment: I like that approach. Fixed that issue you had by adding `isFocusing: function(e) {
                    return true;
                }` and `isBlurring: function(e) {
                    return true;
                }` on the `textareafield`. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you too! Nice trick. I guess we both learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

You could set a keyboard shortcut for it, like that:

```
            xtype: 'textareafield',
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            enableKeyEvents: true, //important
            listeners: {
                keydown: function (a,e){
                    if ((e.altKey)&&(e.keyCode==73)){ //in that case Alt+i , but you could use any other combination                            
                        a.getTriggers().book.el.dom.click();
                    }
                }  
            }
```

Hope that helps